# How install an application with apt-get and restrict it to a specific repo source?

Tags: installation, apt

I used to do something similar with yum on CentOS. I think there was a --enable-repo and --disable-repo param.

Is there something that exists for `apt-get install <some pkg>` that will restrict to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/<somefile>`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by pinning the release using `/etc/apt/preferences`. The man page is `apt_preferences`.  Format is as follows:

```
 Package: *
 Pin: release o=Debian,a=testing
 Pin-Priority: 900
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do that quickly and easily without a wrapper around apt-get to juggle the sources manually.

One option however is to suffix the package you wish to install with the version number required, which will likely be different in each source.

e.g.

```
apt-get install cowsay=3.03-9.2
```

Comment: You can also check the versions and what would be installed using `apt-cache policy cowsay` - then use the resulting version, etc. to specify the package specifically.